# Analytics tools for iOS does not work

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-analytics, flurry

I've tried integrating both Google Analytics and Flurry in my app, but none of these services will log my data. It's like the data never reaches the server. Has anyone experienced this before? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information if you really expect an answer...

Comment: Joseph, provide more context or at least device logs? Its impossible to answer the question without any context.

Comment: @djabi The answer provided has now been accepted, sorry for not doing it sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to wait 24-48h after creating google tracking ID to see results. (Even for real time)

the answer here : [Google Analytics on iOS: events not tracked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877537/google-analytics-on-ios-events-not-tracked#comment42328257_26877537)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Flurry

Start with the basic integration:

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/ios/#get-started

Add these lines of code before you start the Flurry session:

[Flurry setDebugLogEnabled:YES]; 
[Flurry setLogLevel:FlurryLogLevelAll];

You should see a 200 response from Flurry's server in the console logs when the session ends. Be sure to close the app with the Home button.

There is a delay of about 6-8 hours before the session data will show in the Flurry dashboard. If you continue to have issues send an email to support@flurry.com