# How to use Google Analytics for iOS via cocoapods

Tags: google-analytics, swift3, cocoapods, xcode8

In my bridging header, I infinitely get "<Google/Analytics.h> not found"

I followed Google's own tutorial: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift

I've tried the 'pod GoogleAnalytics' methods people have posted.

I've tried all of the suggestions people have posted in other threads.

Is there something else I need to change in the "build settings" ... or does 'pod install' do everything?

---

Bridging Header:
[image: Bridging Header]

Build Settings:
[image: Build Settings]

Podfile:
[image: Podfile]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Swift 4.0 and xcode 9.0.1 finally I resolved.**

For me after 2 days I resolved.. Don't follow Google's old documentation says `#import <Google/Analytics.h>`

1. Go to Terminal type `pod init`
2. Reopen project as workspace obvious after pod workspace is created, open podfile. write `pod 'GoogleAnalytics'` in your pod file before `target 'GoogleAnalytics' do`
3. Go back to Terminal `pod install` you will find frameworks `GAI.h` and other files will be there under pods folder
4. Create `Header.h` file to your root. ***Don't add `#import <Google/Analytics.h>`*** instead import following individually in bridging header file

e.g. in bridging header file remove `#import <Google/Analytics.h>`

```
#import "GAI.h"
#import "GAITracker.h"
#import "GAIFields.h"
#import "GAIDictionaryBuilder.h"
```

5. Point your bridge under Build Settings for target Swift Compiler - General -> Objective-C Bridging Header. write `Header.h` of your bridging file name
6. Add code from google for swift to `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` **Don't forget to replace your tracking id from Google Analytics page**

   ```
       guard let gai = GAI.sharedInstance() else {
           assert(false, "Google Analytics not configured correctly")
       }
       gai.tracker(withTrackingId: "YOUR_TRACKING_ID")
       // Optional: automatically report uncaught exceptions.
       gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true

       // Optional: set Logger to VERBOSE for debug information.
       // Remove before app release.
       gai.logger.logLevel = .verbose;
   ```

Tada.... Run your project...

Comment: Thanks! Correct the quote for `#import GAI.h` in your answer pls.

Comment: Yep... corrected... thanks... I think I should apply in Google for updating there docs to support swift 4.0... as solution worked by not following what they say to import.. lol..

Answer (score 0):

Found some help here (by Matthew Bradshaw): [Use of unresolved identifier GGLContext and GAI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241346/use-of-unresolved-identifier-gglcontext-and-gai)

Seems that cocoapods incorrectly installed, or set the build settings incorrectly (or something strange).

Following his advice, I started from scratch, pod install'd, created the bridging header and imported each individual file (and not <Google/Analytics.h>), then pointed build settings at the bridging header!

Voila, the bridging header is no longer complaining about not being able to find files! Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you should see an example here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/start?ver=swift

---

Start with the sample using the following command from a terminal:

```
$ pod try Google
```

Select the option for AnalyticsExample.xcodeproj from the prompt.